# 750K mortgage and 10K property tax deduction limit - applies to LLC?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, tax-deduction, property-taxes

Does the 750K mortgage and 10K property tax deduction limits apply only to individuals, or LLC and other corporations as well?

Follow-up question: if someone split up property ownership between an individual and an LLC (or several LLCs) so that each one came in under 750K mortgage and 10K property tax, would each of the individuals and LLCs still be able to claim the deduction on the mortgage interest and property taxes as long as each individual / LLC ownership was under the limits?

This question is for the United States, and relates to the recently passed tax bill.